# python regex to extract position of repeated expression sequence

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have data as follows:

```
text = "hello there, a:123ijk^&45b: I am working on this regex a:45o#iu67b: I need to solve it"
```

I want to get only the string sequences between a: and b: . My output should be 
`position('a:123ijk^&45b:')` and `position('a:45o#iu67b:')` . I tried a few regex patterns but it returns between first a: and last b:, so couldn't solve it. As an alternate I have a boring way of writing a loop based solution but want to avoid it.

Appreciate if anyone can can help with this

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to get only the string sequences between a: and b: "*

Maybe like:

```
(?<=a:).+?(?=b:)
```

The `?` in the middle makes the greedy `+` lazy and stops the match when `:b` is ahead the first time. This would now get the values that are actually [in between](https://regex101.com/r/nrNVt9/2)

---

**Edit:**

> *"realized ... my question was also put wrong.. what if I want to include only a not b?"*

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/QNnrHm/1):

```
(?<=\s)a:.+?(?=b:)
```

I included an extra positive lookbehind to make sure the `a:` is preceded by a `\s`.

Comment: And what if I want to include `a` and `b` both in the result ?

Comment: @CARTman, it looks like the other answer has got that covered =)

Comment: Yes, just realized but actually my question was also put wrong.. what if I want to include only `a` not `b` and vice versa

Comment: @CARTman, check the updated answer =)

Comment: Wow, it worked, thanks so much :)

Comment: @CARTman, no worries. If his has helped, please consider to upvote, and don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lazy quantifier:

```
a:(.*?)b:
```